# In an array, is there at least one greater number than all the other numbers in the other array?

Tags: java, arrays

Write an iterative method named ex1, which has two formal parameters to two array of integers a and b.
If a and b contain at least one element, ex1 returns true value, only if all the elements of `b[i ... length-1]` are all smaller than `a[i]`

```
public static boolean ex1(int a[], int b[]){
     boolean p = a != null && b != null; 
     boolean s = false;
     int i = 0;
     int j = 0;
     int cont = 0;
     if (p){
         while( i < a.length && s == false){
             for(j = i; j < b.length; j++){
                 if(a[i] > b[j]){
                     cont++;
                 }
             }
             if(cont == (j - i) + 1){
                 s = true;
             }
             i++;
         }
    }
    return s;
}
```

For the test

```
public class Febbraio0TestEx1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a0 = null;
        int[] a1 = {};
        int[] a2 = {10, 2};
        int[] a3 = {2, 3};
        int[] b0 = null;
        int[] b1 = {};
        int[] b2 = {4, 0, -1, 1, 1};
        int[] b3 = {4, 0, -1, 1, 3};

        System.out.println(Febbraio0.ex1(a0, b0)==false); 
        System.out.println(Febbraio0.ex1(a0, b1)==false); 
        System.out.println(Febbraio0.ex1(a1, b0)==false); 
        System.out.println(Febbraio0.ex1(a1, b1)==false); 
        System.out.println(Febbraio0.ex1(a2, b0)==false); 
        System.out.println(Febbraio0.ex1(a2, b1)==false); 
        System.out.println(Febbraio0.ex1(a2, b3)==true) ; 
        System.out.println(Febbraio0.ex1(a3, b2)==true) ; 
        System.out.println(Febbraio0.ex1(a3, b3)==false); 
    }
}
```

From the tests, it should return all true. But my method is not functional, and I do not understand why.

Comment: "Why is my code not working" is not a valid question for this site. You should provide more details. What are your expected outputs, what are your actual outputs. What do you think can cause these outputs ? Have you tried to debug it to see where it could be wrong ?

Comment: have you debugged your code, and checked whether your conditions work on the values you think they are executed on?

Comment: I've already written the expected outputs. My outputs are all true, except for two comparisons (a2, b3) and (a3, b2). I tried to debug, but everything seems ok. I'm trying to understand why the logic is wrong.

Comment: When you debug you should see what's going wrong. I think it's about your condition to put s to true : `if(cont == (j - i) + 1)`. I don't understand your logic here. If you debug you will see if you enter here. Your code seems to never set s to true and always return false. Check for a case when it should enter your condition what are the values of cont, j, i. It will help you to understand what's going on

Comment: Note that comparisons against `true` or `false` are **obsolete** as the value itself already is a `boolean`. So you could just do `System.out.println(!Febbraio0.ex1(a0, b0));` etc. instead.

Comment: At least add why the code does not work as intended. Which tests do fail? **Edit** your question to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not good at all. I suggest you to look at this problem a different way.

> ex1 returns true value, only if all the elements of b[i ... length-1] are all smaller than a[i]

That means that max elemnt of array b must be smaller than min element of array a. So you can write this in one line and it's a lot better.

```
public static boolean ex1(int a[], int b[]){
      return Collections.max(b) < Collections.min(a);}
```

Comment: Maybe the goal of the exercise was to compute `max` and `min` on his own. Also note that your code requires two iterations of the collection. For large collections this takes double the time though you can compute `max` and `min` in **one pass at the same time**. But I agree that OPs code doesn't look clear and straightforward. For a full answer it would also be good to explain to OP why his method does not work, as this seems to be his primary question.

Comment: I have not used the Collections classes yet. I have not used them for this. But yes, you pointed out to me that it's much simpler than it seemed. Great, I thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "requires two iterations of the collection" they are two different arrays. With that approach you traverse each of the arrays once which is a must since it's not an ordered list or some other sorted structure.

Comment: While elegant, it does not deal with the "if both arrays are nonempty" part.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that they are different. In that case, drop the comment. However, the part with the missing debugging help still remains. The primary question is "*why does my attempt not work?*" and not "*anybody have a working alternative?*". Don't get me wrong, your alternative is clear and good. It's just a hint what I would require for a full answer according to [answer] in order to up-vote.

Comment: OP's homework assignment stated that ex1 should be _"an iterative method"_, not sure this qualifies as one.

Comment: Oh ye I didn't notice ! The approach is still relevant just have to replace Collections.max(), Collections.max() with custom implementations.